# RunAs netonly with credentials saved

Tags: windows, active-directory

I can start a process with `runas /netonly` and `runas /savecred` but I can't use both the flags at the same time.

Is there a way to run a process as a different user remotely without having to type the password every time?

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this is an unsupported option you can provide either /netonly or /savecred but not both:

runas [{/profile | /noprofile}] [/env] **[{/netonly | /savecred}]** [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user: " "

more info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Comment: It is really annoying unfortunately, but I have seen some hints here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain when I have a chance I'll try and apply them.

Answer (score 6):

In [the other answer here Jason rightly notes](https://serverfault.com/a/789049/58957) that `runas /netonly` does not support saving the credentials, and Microsoft [intentionally made it hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116329/1026) to use `runas` with a hard-coded password (from a batch script).

The [suggestion to use the Windows Credential Manager](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66022/15599) that Stefano pointed to in their comment is useful when you want to **always** connect to the given service (i.e. `myserver.mycompany.com:XXX`) using the specified credentials.

For a command-line solution, with behavior similar to runas.exe, but without having to type the password, I found the [RunAs powershell module](https://github.com/gfody/PowershellModules/tree/master/RunAs) (which seems to implement [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628228/1026)) very useful:

1. Install from PowerShell Gallery by running the following in an elevated PowerShell prompt (requires Powershell v5 or Windows 10):

   ```
   Install-Module RunAs
   ```
2. Encrypt the password by running:

   ```
   # change `domain\username` as needed:
   ConvertFrom-SecureString (Get-Credential 'domain\username').Password
   ```

   This will prompt you for the login and the password and print a long hexadecimal number, which you'll have to copy.
3. Now you can do the equivalent of `runas /netonly` using:

   ```
   Import-Module RunAs

   # replace xxxx below with the encrypted password from step 2 (and `domain\username` too)
   # you might want to put this into your profile: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7
   $mycreds = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential('domain\username', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxx'))

   runas -netonly $mycreds "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
   ```

P.S. many resources on the net suggest using [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to run as a different user. After looking up [how that works under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638671/1026), I don't believe it to be a viable alternative to `runas /netonly`